# How to determine which image(s) in a word document are unusually large?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word 2007 document that is now 7MB in size that is being edited by many folks.  I would like to figure out which of the many images in the document is the 'culprit'.  My hunch is likely one or two of them is a bitmap or some other large image.

In smaller documents when this is happened I can do it by trial and error:

1. Remove an Image
2. Save the File
3. Check File size
4. repeat

Is there a more elegant solution to this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can open the docx file in a program like winrar and see all the components (including images) that go into making the document.

Images are stored in the word -> media folder

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you save the Word document as a **Web Page (*.htm; *.html)**, embedded images will be extracted to a `<document>_files` folder in the same location as the new HTML file. From there, you can sort by size and find the culprit.

Comment: This worked - thanks.  Of interest - .emz Files - When folks copy and paste a Visio diagram directly instead of a image - are some of the worst culprits.

Comment: You probably want Visio digrams linked and editable in such cases anyway, I guess.